# Composing email in swift Nil Modelview controler

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to the swift, and I am using an open-source app that requires sending an email when I click on an entry. I am getting these two warnings too. I have attached a screen shot.

Thanks

```
func sendEmail(dateString: String, path: URL, hr_path: URL) {
    
    let composeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    composeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
    
    composeVC.navigationBar.tintColor  = .white
    composeVC.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    
    // Configure email
    // composeVC.setToRecipients(["your@email.here"])
    composeVC.setSubject("Sleep event data for " + dateString)
    composeVC.setMessageBody("Sleep event data attached as CSV", isHTML: false)
    
    if let fileData = NSData(contentsOf: path) {
        print("Motion data loaded.")
        composeVC.addAttachmentData(fileData as Data, mimeType: "text/csv", fileName: "motion_data.csv")
    }
    if let fileData = NSData(contentsOf: hr_path) {
        print("HR data loaded.")
        composeVC.addAttachmentData(fileData as Data, mimeType: "text/csv", fileName: "hr_data.csv")
    }
    
    // Present mail controller
    self.present(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
}

func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController,
                           didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
    
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8B0C6.png)

Answer (score 0):

How do you call sendEmail ? This is exactly the error what is written in the ss. Main thread warning :). You should call sendEmail function in main thread like below.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
    self?.sendEmail(dateString: "sample", path: "URL", hr_path: "URL")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `sendEmail()` function has been called in some background thread.

Whenever you want to init a view controller, or generally, do something with the UI, please do it in the main thread.

So, in this case, because the initialize of the view controller is inside `sendEmail()`, you need to call `sendEmail()` in the main thread, like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
    guard let `self` = self else { return }
    self.sendEmail(dateString: "7/7/2021", path: "myPath", hr_path: "hrPath")
}
```